# Prevent read lock for 2 different threads in spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, synchronization, locking

I have 3 types of users i.e A, B and C.I am reading DB column to fetch the latest id userwise, incrementing it by one and creating new userid from the repository.

```
 Request lastCreatedIdUserWise = requestRepository.findTopByUserIdOrderByCreateDateDesc(user.getUserId());
    Long requestSubscriptionId = 1L;
    if (lastCreatedRequestForSubscription != null) {
        // plus one the last created request id for subscription.
        requestSubscriptionId += lastCreatedRequestForSubscription.getShipRequestIdBySubscription();
    }
    request.setRequestIdBySubscription(shipRequestSubscriptionId);//this saves a new request with new Id
```

I need to put lock for each user when new requests arrive.
When there are multiple requests for User A then need to lock this process(retrieving max id and saving new Id)
When there are requests for different users(ie A or B or C) then let this flow continue(no lock required).

Comment: You're not supposed to do this in application layer. The database can do it for you.

Comment: @JerryChin : Can you please provide a sample/example for it?

Comment: Use SQL eg. `update User set subscriptionId = subscriptionId  + 1 where userId = xx`, make sure isolation level is Repeatable-Read.

Comment: Also, this ID is not getting updated. We are saving a new entity in DB with new userid.

Comment: I see it now, what you really want is a unique id generator.